# Pandas Parse DataFrame Field and Maintain ID Field

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, pandas, dataframe

I have a made-up pandas series that I split on a delimiter:

```
s2 = pd.Series(['2*C316*first_field_name17*second_field_name16*third_field_name2*N311*field value1*Y5*hello2*O30*0*0*'])
split = s2.str.split('*')
```

The general logic to parse this string:

- Asterisks are the delimiter
- Numbers immediately before asterisks identify the length of the following block
- Three indicators

  - C indicates field names will follow
  - N indicates new field values will follow
  - O indicates old field values will follow
  - Numbers immediately after indicators (tough because they are next to numbers before asterisks) identify how many field names or values will follow

The parsing logic and code works on a single pandas series. Therefore, it is less important to understand that than it is to understand applying the logic/code to a dataframe.

I calculate the number of fields in the string (in this case, the `3` in the second block which is `C316`):

```
number_of_fields = int(split[0][1][1:int(split[0][0])])
```

I apply a lot of list splitting to extract the results I need into three separate lists (field names, new values, and old values):

```
i=2
string_length = int(split[0][1][int(split[0][0]):])
field_names_list = []
while i < number_of_fields + 2:
    field_name = split[0][i][0:string_length]
    field_names_list.append(field_name)
    string_length = int(split[0][i][string_length:])
    i+=1

i = 3 + number_of_fields
string_length = int(split[0][2 + number_of_fields][string_length:])
new_values_list = []
while i < 3+number_of_fields*2:
    field_name = split[0][i][0:string_length]
    new_values_list.append(field_name)
    string_length = int(split[0][i][string_length:])
    i+=1

i = 4 + number_of_fields*2
string_length = int(split[0][3 + number_of_fields*2][string_length:])
old_values_list = []
while i <= 3 + number_of_fields*3:
    old_value = split[0][i][0:string_length]
    old_values_list.append(old_value)
    if i == 3 + number_of_fields*3:
        string_length = 0
    else:
        string_length = int(split[0][i][string_length:])
    i+=1
```

I combine the lists into a df with three columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'field_name': field_names_list,
     'new_value': new_values_list,
     'old_value': old_values_list
    })

    field_name          new_value     old_value
0   first_field_name    field value 
1   second_field_name   Y   
2   third_field_name    hello
```

How would I apply this same process to a df with multiple strings? The df would look like this:

```
    row_id      string
0   24  2*C316*first_field_name17*second_field_name16*third_field_name2*N311*field value1*Y5*hello2*O30*0*0*
1   25  2*C316*first_field_name17*second_field_name16*third_field_name2*N311*field value1*Y5*hello2*O30*0*0*
```

I'm unsure how to maintain the `row_id` with the eventual columns. The end result should look like this:

```
    row_id  field_name          new_value      old_value
0   24      first_field_name    field value 
1   24      second_field_name   Y   
2   24      third_field_name    hello
3   25      first_field_name    field value 
4   25      second_field_name   Y   
5   25      third_field_name    hello
```

I know I can concatenate multiple dataframes, but that would come after maintaining the `row_id`. How do I keep the `row_id` with the corresponding values after a series of list slicing operations?

Comment: I'm lost at `number_of_fields = int(split[0][1][1:int(split[0][0])])`. How does this calculate the "numer of fields" ?

Comment: I added some general decoding logic for this string. Essentially, the number after the indicators (C, N, and O) signifies the number of fields there are going to be (in this case 3). The numbers directly before each asterisk, signifies how long the string after the asterisk will be. The first number is 2, so the string after the first asterisk is 2 characters long or `C3`.